# Error in types in haskell

Tags: haskell, types

I get this error:

```
Type error in application
*** Expression     : length (filter (flip (==) x))
*** Term           : filter (flip (==) x)
*** Type           : [b] -> [b]
*** Does not match : [a]
```

This is my code:

```
numocc::(Eq a) => a -> [[a]] -> [Int]
numocc = map.((length.).(f))

f:: (Eq a) => a -> [a] -> a
f = filter.(flip (==))
```

I cannot understand the types. Can anybody help me?

Comment: Why are you `flip`ping `==`? It should be commutative.

Comment: Without filpping this error is still actually

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I put the definition of `f` in ghci, I get:

```
Expected type: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> a
  Actual type: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
In the first argument of `(.)', namely `filter'
In the expression: filter . (flip (==))
```

In other words, what results here is a list of type a, when a single instance of type a is expected.
If you're applying a predicate to a list, and the result should be a single instance, then you'll probably want to make a fold of some kind.

Changing the type of `f` to

```
f:: (Eq a) => a -> [a] -> [a]
```

makes this code compile.

Answer (score 4):

You are trying way too hard to be point free, just use:

```
f :: (Eq a) => a -> [a] -> [a]
f x = filter (== x)
```

and then:

```
numocc :: (Eq a) => a -> [[a]] -> [Int]
numocc x = map (length . f x)
```

[<kbd>Live demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bebf26af109eebb1)

Comment: Unfortunetlly i have to be point free because this is my task

Comment: @KoinArab Your task is write unreadable code for the sake of being point free?

Comment: Exacly. It's one of my test exercises.

Comment: I agree with you but i do nothing with this.

Comment: @KoinArab Use the `pointfree` program from the Wild Wide Web to convert your functions to point-free style.

Comment: @n.m., I have actually used lambdabot's @pl feature for real live code (to produce `(.)` that could actually be turned to coercing `(#.)` or `(.#)`, not just to make things unreadable).